# How can I get the Cell Reference of a Named Range in Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2007, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function

I solved the issue, but I'm wondering if there's a better way to do this. What I have is a column of some named ranges ("NAME"), and I want a formula to the right that looks up the named range and gives me the cell reference ("C352").

I eventually solved it with this:

```
=CHAR(64+COLUMN(INDIRECT(C2, FALSE)))&ROW(INDIRECT(C2, FALSE))
```

The CHAR part is to translate the column number (3) to the letter (C), and it doesn't work past column Z.

This shouldn't be the best way to do it. I saw some VBA solutions, is that the only possible way to do this better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
=ADDRESS(ROW(INDIRECT(C2)),COLUMN(INDIRECT(C2)),4,1)
```

How it works

- `INDIRECT(C2)` returns a reference address specified by `C2`.  The range refered to by the named range in this case.
- `ROW( ... )` returns the row of the cell specified
- `COLUMN( ... )` ditto for column
- `ADDRESS( r, c, 4, 1)` returns the address or row `r`, column `c`. `4` means relative (ie no `$`'s. `1` means `A1` style. So  `ADDRESS(ROW( ... ),COLUMN( ... ),4,1)` will be the address of the named range in `A1` notation

Answer (score 3):

If you can live with $ in the reference you could use:

```
=CELL("address",INDIRECT(C1))
```

or:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(CELL("address",INDIRECT(C1)),"$",)
```

to drop the $

Answer (score 2):

```
=ADDRESS(ROW(INDIRECT(C2, FALSE)), COLUMN(INDIRECT(C2, FALSE)), abs_num)
```

where *abs_num* is 1 to return an absolute address (e.g., "`$C$352`"), 4 to return a relative address (e.g., "`C352`"), or 2 for "`C$352`", or 3 for "`$C352`".  (*abs_num* defaults to 1 (i.e., absolute) if omitted.)

Comment: This is the most direct way to get this? There's nothing like `=ADDRESS(C2)` or similar?